# Вывод части строки между определнными позициями символов c++

Tags: c++, строки, char, hex

Есть строка, в ней, к прмеру, 100 символов, но необходимо вывести только часть строки между 30 и 70 символом, как такое сделать на c++?

Comment: ` std::cout << std::string_view(  str + 30,  (70-30)  ) <<std::endl`

Comment: `putchar(str[i]);` в цикле

Answer (score 0):

Не делал банальных проверок на ввод некорректных чисел, с этим вы уже сами справитесь.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[256] = "Output part of a string between certain character positions c++";
    int first = 0;
    int last = 0;
    cin >> first >> last;
    for (int i = first; i < last; i++) {
        cout << str[i];
    }
}
```